# How can I find the source file that causes the print_r display in PHP

Tags: php, debugging

I'm wondering how would someone debug to find the source file (and perhaps line number in the code) that causes the `print_r`? Or is there a package that could be use for this kind of debugging during page load? Similar idea like console.log in the dev tool.

Comment: I'd say your text editor's search is the best way.

Comment: Use echo and exit. best method to debug

Comment: @deceze not ideal if there are a lot of print_r everywhere with folders from different plugin authors.

Comment: Sure, it's not great, but there's no real way to track the origin of output besides a manual search. Having wild `print_r` statements in production code is arguably pretty darn terrible code, so you're already screwed either way. ;o)

Answer (score -1):

Probably the debug_print_backtrace() from PHP can help you.
These way you can see all the functions that have been called.

More details: http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-print-backtrace.php